# Editing: am I just doing it wrong?

Tags: discussion, edits

I'm trying to contribute by editing posts where code is formatted badly, the English is poor, or both. I've had a couple of edits rejected under the "doesn't make it even a little bit easier to read" reason, which I found dubious enough, but [I just had a reviewer propose rejection](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10566225) for "this edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer."

I'm reading through my changes, which I believe to be fair and useful, and I can't imagine where that came from. So, either I have misunderstood the point of editing, or the people who review edits have a very different set of criteria to me. Suggestions?

Ultimately my change got accepted, so it's possible I'm just worrying over nothing; it might just have been one person with Very Particular Views on edits.

Comment: Say hello to robot reviewers. You did nothing wrong here.

Comment: @vard: I genuinely did not know that was a thing. Time for some Googling!

Comment: I don't mean robot like bots, it's just reviewers who easily reject an edit if they see that too much things changed without taking time to see if the edit is appropriate. On the other side, there is also reviewers who accept everything and probably don't spend more than 5 seconds on a review.

Comment: Ah; I guess that probably means there's a badge or a hat or a scarf or something if people get through enough edits.

Comment: Though when you make an edit be sure to improve all what you can improve. You could have fixed the capitalization ("NOT", "FIRST", "ALL").

Comment: Yes you get a silver badge for 250 reviews, and a gold one for 1000 reviews. Though review audits are there to warn reviewers when they do wrong reviews. It can still be ignored though.

Comment: Understood; I did look at that very carefully and decided to leave it as the author wrote it. When it comes to "you've done your code tag wrong" it's a binary choice between right and wrong; when it comes to "you've used CAPS rather than *italics*" I feel that's more of a style question, so I followed the "always respect the author" rule and left it.

Comment: Well that's minor, though _italic_ should be used to emphasize, which is what he means by using caps. But I agree that's minor and can be left of, it's just a suggestion.

Comment: Or the reviewer just didn't think it was a good edit. It is a system based on subjectivity of course. If every case had a concrete 1 or 0 answer we wouldn't need a review queue.

Comment: @KevinB I understand that's it's subjective, but the "should have been written as an answer" reason seems very far off base in this case, no?

Comment: definitely seems off base, but without input from the reviewer we can only speculate. This reviewer in particular doesn't appear to have a record much different from the other reviewers who approved.